# Add suffix to duplicates where additional column equals specific string

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to add a suffix of `-US` to all values which are duplicates, and that an additoanl `country` column is equal to `US`. A snippet of my DataFrame `df` is seen below.

```
 product_num      country
 101              US
 101              Ireland
 302              US
 303              Scotland
 304              France
 305              US
 305              Germany
 306              US
 307              US
```

My desired output is seen below.

```
   product_num      country
     101-US           US
     101              Ireland
     302              US
     303              Scotland
     304              France
     305-US           US
     305              Germany
     306              US
     307              US
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create mask by chaining [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep='False'` for all dupes and compare `country` column with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and set only filtered rows to strings with added suffix string:

```
m = df.duplicated('product_num', keep=False) & df['country'].eq('US')
df.loc[m, 'product_num'] = df.loc[m, 'product_num'].astype(str) + '-US'
```

Alternative solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['product_num'] = np.where(m, df['product_num'].astype(str) + '-US', df['product_num'])

print (df)
  product_num   country
0      101-US        US
1         101   Ireland
2         302        US
3         303  Scotland
4         304    France
5      305-US        US
6         305   Germany
7         306        US
8         307        US
```